# AWS S3DownloadTask is Unable to resolve host: No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to download from my Amazon S3 bucket on Android, although i'm getting this error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "cognito-identity.us-west-2.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
```

on this line

```
Download down = manager.download(AWSClientManager.S3_BUCKET_NAME, fileToDownload, file);
```

I'm unsure why it would be using **us-west-2** when the default for my ***CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider*** is **us-east-1**

Even so, the following locatinos for my s3 storage have the exact same files:

```
https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-east-1
https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=us-west-2
```

I have no idea why I am getting the error above, can somebody help please?

Hi @Mark, 
My CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider is set to US_EAST_1

I am using AmazonS3Client to download S3 files.. I think this might be the issue.  I am explicitly setting the region, although it seems to completely disregard this.

This is my code where it errors:

```
private S3TaskResult downloadResources(String fileToDownload) {

        S3TaskResult result = new S3TaskResult();
        File file = new File(downloadDirectory, fileToDownload);

        try {

            manager.getAmazonS3Client().setRegion(com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
            Download down = manager.download(AWSClientManager.S3_BUCKET_NAME, fileToDownload, file);
            down.addProgressListener(this);
            down.waitForCompletion();

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            // TODO:  FIGURE OUT WHY IT ERRORS HERE :(
            result.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage()); 
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: fwiw: the console region doesn't convey any meaningful info when looking at S3, and us-west-2 doesn't have a [cognito identity endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cognito_identity_region) so the error is accurate, though I realize that isn't much consolation -- it isn't clear why your code is trying to use us-west-2.

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael, the link you provided gave me some more insight into the AWS endpoints :)  Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to use Amazon Cognito is us-west-2.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "cognito-identity.us-west-2.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
```

Currently, Amazon Cognito is only available in us-east-1, eu-west-1, and ap-northeast-1.

This does not mean you cannot use Cognito credentials to access S3 buckets in other regions, you simply need set Cognito to use one of the above mentioned regions (and set up your identity pool in that region). Then set your S3 client to use whichever region your bucket is in.

Make sure you are setting up your Credentials Provider with the correct region:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
   getApplicationContext(), // Context
   "IDENTITY_POOL_ID", // Identity Pool ID
   Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
);
```

As described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/getting-credentials/

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because it's correct.  The problem i had was that i was setting the region as Default on my startup class (the code that is used when the user is already logged in and then re-open the app) and US_EAST_1 on my login class.  I forgot to check my startup class for this :(

I changed my startup class to US_EAST_1 and it worked :)  
I knew it was something i was overlooking but just couldn't find where it was.  Thanks for the help

Comment: You're awesome...life saver